# ¿Como puedo evitar el full table scan?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image]

No entiendo porque si la fecha de entrega ya tiene un índice me sigue marcando un full table scan y quisiera saber que ocupo para realizar la instrucción comentada evitando el full table scan

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo hice de esta otra manera pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema y el punto aquí
es optimizar la consulta, o será que simplemente no hay manera?

Comment: El indice es fecha_entrega, vos estas usando en el where una funcion contra fecha_entrega. La DB piensa que no le conviene usar el indice porque no puede aplicar la funcion al indice (y esto lo supongo, tal vez esta comprimido o algo) y entonces le conviene ir directamente a la tabla y aplicar la funcion campo a campo.. o tal vez, el indice este desactualizado y tengas que actualizarlo primero...

Comment: Sabrás otra manera de obtener el mes sin importar el año?

Answer (score 1):

Releyendo el comentario de @gbianchi me he dado cuenta de que el problema está en usar una función contra el campo. En vez de utilizar directamente la fecha, tal que así:

```
SELECT * FROM pedido
  WHERE fecha_entrega 
  BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-05-31';
```

Lo que evitará el `full scan table`:

```
+------+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pedido | range | fecha_entrega | fecha_entrega | 4       | NULL | 2    | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
```

Aporto el dataset para las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE pedido(
  id_pedido int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha_entrega date,
  n_pedido int
  );
ALTER TABLE pedido ADD INDEX(fecha_entrega);
INSERT INTO pedido (fecha_entrega, n_pedido) VALUES
  ('2022-01-04',220001),
  ('2022-02-06',220002),
  ('2022-03-03',220003),
  ('2022-05-15',220004),
  ('2022-05-11',220005),
  ('2022-06-01',220006);
```